# How to index 'pages' that are views, while using access control to hide component content?

Tags: views, users, search

I have a site that relies on some complicated relations to compose views for parameterized site 'pages', but don't want anon users to see the raw unformatted bits that are linked together to form these pages. I use access control to keep those private, and disable query rewriting so the same users can see the views, but this seems to mean anon page searches don't find the pages containing the restricted content, even when I *think* I'm selecting the page search settings correctly and including the paths to these views. Would really appreciate some suggestions....

Comment: Disabling query rewriting is dangerous. Make sure you know the implications. It means pretty much all listings on your site will not adhere to your access control rules anymore.

Comment: Are you using the basic drupal core search? - What access control modules are you using?

Comment: Also, how are you disabling query rewriting?

Comment: I'm only doing in in particular view blocks, in the views > block > advanced settings > other section. Using the Content Access module (7.x-1.2-beta2) w/ Drupal 7.22. It's the only way I could figure to let the full composite pages be seen by anon users without dishing out all the messy bits out of context. I'm also using the Search by Page module (and sub-modules) which I was hoping would give me more control of this situation, but if so, I haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: So I've ended up using the Rabbit Hole module, which lets me do exactly what I wanted, indexing everything but redirecting anon users to appropriate views via tokens. As a bonus, after liberalizing the access for some of these entities I can un-disable query rewriting for the views that use them.